# What is proper order of resolving players actions?

Tags: house-rules, jamaica

In Jamaica each player selects a card with two actions on it. The left action is connected to the **Morning** die and the right one to the **Evening** die. So, basically there is somerhing that happens for every player in the morning and then later, in the evening.

The way we played our first game was that we woukd resolve morning action of each player first, starting with the captain of the turn. Then, we would go to the evening phase and resolve second action of each player in the same order. That's how I understood the rules, since morning comes to all residents of Jamaica at the same time, not after one of them has already seen an evening.

I watched a few playthroughs on the youtube and I noticed that this is not how other people are playing the game. So, I suspect I got this order of action rule wrong.

So, my questions are:

- are both actions of the player to be resolved before moving to the next player? Is the Morning/Evening confusion just an effect of poor choise of wording?
- playing with our simultaneous Morning actions rule, how would you say it affects the gameplay? Does it give you more or less control of the course of the game? Does it make it more exciting? Increase battle frequency? Randomness?

I believe that resolving Morning actions for all players seems more logical and it does minimise the downtime between player's involvement in the game, little as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules seem very explicit.

"The captain turns his over and carries out the two actions"

"In turn, the other players do the same: they turn over their card and carry out the two actions"

I can't comment on what the effect of your house rule would be, but it clearly is not the intended way to play.